# wamp is not working and showing red icon on system tray please provide me a precise note for it

Tags: php, networking, web, developer-tools

**strong text**I have installed wamp server but initially showing red icon & not responding recommend  a exact working process .

Comment: red icon means which type of icon?

Comment: have you started the Apache on Wamp ?? just right click on that icon and start all services. then propably it will turn into green color icon.

Comment: If I'm understanding you your question is "my server does not work, please tell me why". I think that may me a little too wide a question to get a polite answer.

Comment: Your http://YOURHOST/phpmyadmin, working?

Comment: if your skype is running then you need to change port in skype or close skype and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

If the wamp manager icon in the system tray is RED then neither apache or mysql has started correctly.

The ONLINE is something else completely. It says you have used the "Put Online" which just changes the apache config to allow access from any ip address or when Offline to only allow access from localhost, 127.0.0.1

Are you sure you dont have something else using port 80? IIS is most likely.
Run wampmanager->apache->services->test port 80 see what it says.

Have a look at your Windows Event Viewer, this will probably give you a clue to why apache and mysql have not started. Also te apache and mysql error logs.

When you get a clue drop back with a bit more information.

You could also try reading through this once you get apache and mysql running, by the way they are called wampapache and wampmysql in your services list.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after looking / eliminating all alternates. Run the wampmanager.exe through task scheduler as at startup.

After restarting the server / desktop, go to task manager and select the "Aestan Tray menu" which is nothing but wampmanager.exe
Right click and select the properties window. As shown in the screen, click on the "Run Compatibility Troubleshooter". Follow the screen and based on your OS, it would show the compatible OS. [image]
Select the OS and presto, the icon appears on the tray.

Best of luck.
Sriram